# System.Threading.Tasks and FileStream

Tags: c#, filestream, task

I am trying to read data from different files on network using FileStream object. 
So I created Tasks (System.Threading.Tasks) to read parts of the files required.

Quite surprised by the behaviour. These Tasks throws an error :

```
int_ReadBytes = stm_BaseStream.Read (byt_buffer, 0, ( int ) ( int_RecordLength * uint_BufferThis ));

if (int_ReadBytes != ( int_RecordLength * uint_BufferThis ))
{
       throw new Exception ("Could not read record");
       // throws an error here. 
}
```

Anyone used Task with FileStream objects, or has any idea why I am getting this issue? 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you declare stm_BaseStream in the Task or out of it ?

Comment: Maybe you are at the end of the file?

Comment: why are you using variable names like that? imho they are horrible. 1. do not prefix variables with their types. 2. `BaseStream` is not a very good variable name. `streamToCopy` would be nicer.

Comment: How do you use the Tasks? What is the exact error? Any byte read before the error? etc etc

Comment: @Marino stm_BaseStream is declared in a class and the task uses the instantiated object to perform the read process.

Answer (score 0):

what is the returned value of `int_ReadBytes`? It may not be equal to `(int_RecordLength * uint_BufferThis)` simply because there are not enough bytes in the file to read, which will casue your code to throw an exception.

Comment: nope its not the EOF and its still got enough it can read. If I set the code to run again in debug by dragging the run pointer it works fine.